# Convert index floats back to datetime

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe where the Index consists of dates:

```
Index                      Close
---                        ---
2020-04-24 15:50:00        2415.88
2020-04-24 15:55:00        2415.23
2020-04-24 16:00:00        2415.21
1.5877443e+18              nan
1.5877446e+18              nan
1.5877449e+18              nan
```

Long story short, I use datetime but the library I'm using requires floats, so the future date indexes it ends up calculating appends them as floats too.

How can I convert all of those end rows with float indexes back to datetime so I can plot?

Here is where the library is using the date floats (I can alter it if needed):

```
ext_beginning = decimal.Decimal(last_date+period)
ext_end = decimal.Decimal(last_date + ((period*cloud_displacement)+period))
dates_ext = list(self.drange(ext_beginning, ext_end, str(period)))
dates_ext_df = pd.DataFrame({"Date": dates_ext})
dates_ext_df.index = dates_ext # also update the df index
ohcl_df = ohcl_df.append(dates_ext_df)
```

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Have you tried anything, done any research?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest is to to convert `dates_ext` to `Timestamp` before assigning it to the index of the new rows:

```
dates_ext_df.index = pd.to_datetime(dates_ext, unit='ns')
ohcl_df = ohcl_df.append(dates_ext_df)
```